# How do you write a generic Go function that allows pointers to multiple primitive types?

Tags: go, generics

I'm trying to use Go generics to write a function to cut down some of the boilerplate if/else blocks in our code. I came up with [something that works for a single type parameter](https://go.dev/play/p/S4lXGp8wfES) as follows:

```
func valueOrNil[T *int](value T) any {
    if value == nil {
        return nil
    }
    return *value
}
```

While this works fine, it's not really useful since it only allows `*int`, and I want this code to work with any primitive type. I tried to extend that to support a second type, [as follows](https://go.dev/play/p/zRoI2aL2Qxa):

```
func valueOrNil[T *int | *uint](value T) any {
    if value == nil {
        return nil
    }
    return *value
}
```

However, this variation fails with a compiler error:

```
invalid operation: pointers of value (variable of type T constrained by *int|*uint) must have identical base types
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here, or is something like this just "not supported"?

Comment: @blackgreen, because in my case the `nil` value is important. The data is being passed down to a SQL driver eventually, and `nil` has a different meaning than the zero value to the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trouble seems to be that you're trying to be generic over **a pointer** to the type rather than the **type itself**. If we move the pointer to be on the parameter itself rather than the type parameter, it works.

Explanation is below, but here is the working code:

```golang
func valueOrNil[T ~int | ~uint](value *T) T {
    if value == nil {
        var zero T
        return zero
    }
    return *value
}
```

---

So instead of this (which doesn't work):

```golang
func valueOrNil[T *int | *uint](value T) any
```

You could do this:

```golang
func valueOrNil[T int | uint](value *T) any
```

However, you may want to take it a step further and handle underlying types:

```golang
func valueOrNil[T ~int | ~uint](value *T) any
```

This would allow a custom type to be used with the function:

```golang
type Thing int

var thing Thing
println(valueOrNil(thing))
```

---

Another facet you may want to consider is being generic over the return type as well. You can do so using the same `T` parameter.

For example:

```golang
func valueOrNil([T ~int | ~uint](value *T) T
```

But this means you would need to change part of the implementation. Instead of this:

```golang
if value == nil {
    return nil
}
```

You could do something like this:

```golang
if value == nil {
    var zero T
    return zero
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer I accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71623780/) from [Miquella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16313/miquella) (thanks for the insights; I learned something about the usage of `~`, too) made me realize that I don't actually need to specify a specific type once I move the `*` onto the parameter type, so [this is what I ended up with](https://go.dev/play/p/yPwCrRQ8Af8):

```
func valueOrNil[T any](value *T) any {
    if value == nil {
        return nil
    }
    return *value
}
```